# adjusting amount of hysteresis band

Tags: controller, hysteresis, time-constant

How is the amount of hysteresis band in the on/off controller adjusted?

I know that there should be a relation with time constant but I can't find the exact proportion.

Read so many papers but didn't get the answer.

Comment: Reading papers will probably not really help you here – this is textbook / exercise book material, not paper material, because basic controllers aren't subject of research of the last years.

Comment: But it's not really clear what the objectives on adjusting the bands would be! What's the thing you want to adjust them *for*? You usually just literally look at the application and/or the input signals and say "ah, yeah, that's the right hysteresis band", because an on/off controller mostly makes sense in cases where you either have an outer continuous-valued controller, or your plant is so slow that an on-off controller comes close to a continuous-valued controller (cf. PWM)

Comment: Could you maybe add an example of where you apply an on/off controller with a hysteresis band, and explain the external factors that would lead to something being a good or a bad setting?

Comment: There is not a one-size fits all. Far from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hysteresis is the difference or "deadband" required in the PV (process variable) between 'on' and 'off', with the setpoint somewhere within the deadband (not necessarily in the center).

The closed-loop system will likely oscillate (not necessarily symmetrically) about the deadband, and the details of that depend on the transfer function of the plant. The amount of oscillation may be considerably more than the deadband, or it might not be much more. For example, if you have a poorly designed thermal system with a whole lot of heat capacity in the heater, lots of heat capacity in the sensor and poor coupling (or mass transfer coupling) between the two you can have the temperature continue to rise for a long time after the heater turns off, and the same on the other side of the deadband when it is cooling and the sensor retains heat to keep the heater off. If it's a first order system then there won't be any overshoot or undershoot, but that's pretty rare in reality.

Typically you would pick a deadband that does not cause too frequent on/off switching (because that can cause problems, particularly with mechanical parts such as contactors or refrigeration systems) yet allows the PV to be maintained "close enough" to the setpoint. When you know the transfer function of the plant, the allowable variation and the target maximum switching frequency you can decide the required deadband.

Comment: Dead-band is something else; it's not hysteresis or caused by hysteresis.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadband#Hysteresis_versus_Deadband

Comment: @Andyaka That's the term we always used for it, on a two position controller. [Here](https://automationforum.co/two-position-control/) is the usage I'm talking about. It's also called dead zone, "gap", differential. But thanks for the reference, maybe worth avoiding the term in this context.